# Image appears when hovering over listed item text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Javascript to `hover` over to reveal an `image` when on my navigation. The problem occurs when the list on my navigation overflows and needs to be scrollable. The `image` will appear in a similar position at the top, therefore cropping the image at a place that breaks a clean functionality. I want the `image` to always appear next to the correct text along with appearing below the text.

To have it appear below the text I inserted a `#insertimage` in the`html` but I'm unsure I am correctly inserting this in a proper manner as it ends up covering the last listed item or if I insert it at the beginning it will cover that.

So I am utilising the template function from here https://codepen.io/danoszz/pen/ORjGpa and have modified it to my JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/jhagmgxv/

How would this be achieved? Would I have to track the position of the listing? How can I do that?

```
function previewImages() {
  /* CONFIG */

  xOffset = 280;
  yOffset = 380;

  // these 2 variable determine popup's distance from the cursor
  // you might want to adjust to get the right result

  /* END CONFIG */

  $("a.imagereveal").hover(function(e) {

      var $this = $(this); // caching $(this)

      $("#insertimage").append("<div id='previewImage'><img src='" + this.rel + "' alt='rens preview image' />" + "</div>");

      $("#previewImage")
        .css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
        .css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
        .fadeIn("fast");
  },
  function() {
      $("#previewImage").remove();
  });

  $("a.screenshot").mousemove(function(e) {
    $("#previewImage")
      .css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
      .css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
  });
};

previewImages();
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly, your problem is the image on rollover appear out of the frame when user scrolls down...
To achive this you need to know how many pixel the user scrolls down, than add this value to the image position.

First of all i added an **unique id** to an element inside the scrollable content, i choose the first `<div>` inside the first `<a>` element, but it might be another of course...

```
    <div class="nav-underline nav-title" id="checkScroll">
      Name
    </div>
```

than in the javascript i tracked the number of pixed scrolled by the element **#checkScroll**

```
var scroll=$("#checkScroll").offset().top;
```

to be checked every time the `.hover` event fires...

than I subtract those pixel number to the placement of the image:

```
.css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset -scroll) + "px")
.css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
```

For the texting purpose of mi jsFiddle i set thos variables to:

```
  xOffset = 100;
  yOffset = 200;
```

In this way images are cleary visible in the exemple; they must be set, of course, accordling the needs of your layout.

https://jsfiddle.net/jhagmgxv/1/

Comment: OK Great that's very nearly there! Thank you. Would I be able to check the position of the page and if near the bottom it offsets the position and places it higher? As some of the items when hovered at the bottom of the page are also cropped.